# Laravel / PHP: How to address 1h discrepancy in ICS file

Tags: php, laravel, icalendar

I looked through many, if not all, of the questions associated with timezone discrepancies in Laravel but don't think I've seen the answer for this issue.

My application allows people to create events setting the start and end times for an event with a specified timezone that applies to each.

I can confirm that config/app.php has the line:

```
'timezone' => 'America/New_York'
```

I have the following (abbreviated) ics file that Laravel is generating:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Event Name
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUBJECT:Meeting Name
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20190311T022400
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20190409T183000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20190409T193000
LOCATION:2833@orgname.org:Place
SUMMARY:Sample Title
DESCRIPTION:We look forward to seeing you. Thank you!
URL;VALUE=URI:http://localhost/events/PMORT2019_04
UID:20190409T183000438@blah.org
SEQUENCE:0
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTSTAMP:20190409T130438
LAST-MODIFIED:20190409T130437
ORGANIZER;CN=OrgName:MAILTO:events@orgname.org
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:Confirmed
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:Confirmed
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The ICS file shows that 1830 (6:30pm) is the start with 1930 (7:30pm) as the end time.  This is what was entered as input and it is what I'd expect to see when opening the ICS file.

However, when I open the resulting ICS file on a windows machine (in the same timezone) Outlook is showing a 7:30pm-8:30pm timeframe which is incorrect.

Comment: Does this timezone have daylight saving time?

Comment: America/New_York does have DST and if the time is at 6:30pm, then it isn't a coding issue.  It seems like your computer is not respecting DST if it's showing up at 7:30.

Comment: Yes it does have DST in it.  The computer I'm using to test and at least 1 other computer--the original person who reported this issue--is causing this to happen.  On my computer, I know that the timezone is set to have DST and be in the Eastern timezone which is still the -05h offset.  I don't know if Windows/Outlook has a different setting or something to represent the timezone but I need to account for it and make sure it's right because many users will, likely, have Outlook.

Comment: @Phil EDT is -04h offset from UTC, not -05.

Comment: That's fair.  I was mentioning the -05 offset as listed for the "Eastern Time (US & Canada)" timezone (per Windows) which also has a checkbox selected to "Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time."  I mention it because, unlike Linux/Unix systems, it doesn't match the "America/New_York" timezone selection exactly.  I don't know if that's the cause or not.

Comment: Windows doesn't always handle daylight saving changes very well.